# Kivy: How can I loop through data from a text file and paste it as a list on my screen all within their own label?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am able to display text from the text file on to the UI but I don't know how to give each piece of text its own label so I am able to evenly spread the text out on screen.

[image: The current result of my problem.]

*.py

```
#imported from kivy framework
from kivy.app import App
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.image import Image
import dictionaryData
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
import os

class Main_Screen(Screen):
    pass


class Dictionary_Screen(Screen):
    def on_enter(self):
        self.Data()

    def Data(self):
        i = 0
        print("trigger")
        file1 = open('dict.txt','r')
        for lines in file1:
            i +=1
            fields = lines.split(',')
            print('I draw label')
            Data = (fields[0], fields[1])
            Title,Description = Data
            #   page is an object
            page = dictionaryData.Dictionary(Title,Description)
            page.formatData()
            work = page.placeholder()
            flipper = page.placeholder()
            self.add_widget(Label(text = flipper, pos=(i*00, 100)))
            self.ids["textFile"].text += flipper + '\n'

#class for all screens
class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
   pass

class MainApp(MDApp):
    pass
MainApp().run()
```

*.kv

```
#:kivy 1.0
#:import hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
#styles that will apply to all intences for each tag
<MDRaisedButton>:
    font_size:18
<Label>:
    color: 0,0,0,1
#declaring screen managers and printing them in this order
ScreenManagement:
    Main_Screen:
        name: "Main_Screen"
    Dictionary_Screen:
        name: "Dictionary_Screen"
<Main_Screen>:
    Button:
        text: "Dictionary"
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "Dictionary_Screen"
<Dictionary_Screen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: 10
        padding: 50
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: hex('#000')
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.5
        GridLayout:
            rows: 3
            cols: 3
            padding: 10
            spacing: 10
            Label:
                id:textFile
                color: (1,0,1,1)
```

Data from the text file goes through a class where it get properly formatted and as you can see by the image it appears fine on screen but its all packed together and not evenly separated.

The purple text is just me hard coding the text using a label in the kv file but I plan to have more than 50 lines that I want to display and hard coding each one does not seem like the right way to go about it.

Is there a way I'm able to give each piece of text it's own label or some how even spread the text out so it appears as a list on screen?

Below is data just in case for reference.

Class module that gets imported and processes the text file

```
#   class
class Dictionary:
    #   Dunder init asigns values to varibles each time code is exacuted.
    def __init__(self,title,description):
        self.title = title
        self.description = description

    def formatData(self):
        print("Title: {} Description {}".format(self.title,self.description))

    def placeholder(self):
        return "Title: {} Description {}".format(self.title,self.description)
```

dict.txt

```
CPU,CPU_INFORMATION
RAM,RAM_INFORMATION
SOMETHING,SOMETHING_INFORMATION
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Try just adding lines to one `Label`, rather than adding multiple `Labels`. Something like `self.root.???.ids.testing.text += flipper + '\n'`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will edit the question so that it has a minimal reproducible example. I tried what you said in your second comment and it did exactly what I wanted but would it be possible to put them into different labels, because in the future I would like each one to be a collapsible menu, where it just shows the title and once clicked on it will expand and show the entire information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is a simple one. Try changing the line:

```
self.add_widget(Label(text = flipper, pos=(i*00, 100)))
```

to something like:

```
self.add_widget(Label(text = flipper, pos=(00, i*50)))
```

Or, if you add an `id` to your `BoxLayout`:

```
<Dictionary_Screen>:
    BoxLayout:
        id: box
```

Then you can use:

```
self.ids.box.add_widget(Label(text = flipper))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! that was a big help. One more little question, I turned the label's into buttons, am I able to create an "on_press" that would create a label under each button which would hold the bulk of information for each button? Sort of like a drop down menu, then once clicked on again would hide the label?

Comment: I suggest that you give it a try. You could do it as you described, or actually use a `DropDown`. See what you can do, then post a new question if you get stuck.